# How to consider differentiability of this function $y=\arctan(x)+x*sgn(x-1)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry

I tried considering differentiability of y=arctan(x) with this formula  $f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ for certain points and it was (p.s how to consider differentiability for all points).

On the other hand $$\text{sgn}(x-1)=\begin{cases} 1, & x>1\\0, &  x=1\\-1, & x<1 \end{cases}$$
RHL≠LHL implies that $$\lim_{x\to 1 }sgn(x-1) $$ does not exist so the function y=sgn(x-1) is not continous at x=1 that means that is not differentiable at x=1 .

Need a bit help to summarize all of this Calculus I problem .

P.s i mean how to consider main function $y=\arctan(x)+x*sgn(x-1)$ differentiability ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not even continuous at $x=1$. And from contraposition:
$$\text{differentiable}\Rightarrow  \text{continuous}$$
$$  \text{not continuous}\Rightarrow \text{not differentiable}$$
So the function is not differentiable at the point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Marek but based in the graph I can understand that is not differentiable at x=1 but i need to prove that mathematically :)

Comment: My proof is mathematical. Contraposition is the law of logic. And differentiability implies continuity is a known fact.

Comment: And if you want to prove the discontinuity, count the left and right limit.

Comment: Thank you @Marek :)